# Tab content not showing properly with CSS Grid areas and JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to set up a JS based tab navigation but somehow the Tab content doesnt show properly.

The JS code seems off but I cannot find the error.

I just want the Tab Content to show that belongs to one  tab.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The Code looks like this:

```js
        function openPage(e, pageName) {
          // Declare all variables
          let i, content, tabLinks;
          // Get all elements with class="tabs_content" and hide them
             content = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs_content");
          for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
            content[i].style.display = "none";
          }

          // Get all elements with class="tabs_button" and remove the class "active"
            tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs_button");
            for (i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
            tabLinks[i].className = tabLinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
          }
          // Show the current tab, and add an "active" class to the link that opened the tab
          document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
          e.currentTarget.className += " active";
            }
          // Get the element with id="defaultOpen" and click on it
          document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
        .wrapper{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
            border:1px solid #cccccc;
            padding: 15px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            grid-template-areas:
                'nav main '
                'nav main'
        }

        .tabs_sidebar {
            grid-area: nav;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background: #cccccc;
        }

        section {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            min-height: 400px;
        }
        .tabs_content {
            grid-area: main;
            background: #f6e3e3;
            padding-left: 15px;
            font-size: 1rem;
        }

        .tabs_button {
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #eeeeee;
            border: none;
            width: 100%;
            outline: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            font-size: 1rem;
        }
        .tabs_button:active {
            background: #dddddd;
        }
        .tabs_button:not(:last-of-type){
            border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav class="tabs_sidebar">
            <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(e, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
            <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(e, 'News')">News</button>
            <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(e, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
        </nav>

        <section class="tabs_content tabs_content--active">
            <div id="Home" class="tabs_content">
            <h2>Tab #1</h2>
            <p>Content Page 1 </p>
             </div>

            <div class="tabs_content">
            <h2>Tab #2</h2>
            <p>Content Page 2 </p>
            </div>

            <div class="tabs_content">
            <h2>Tab #3</h2>
            <p>Content Page 3</p>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
```

I cannot find the error, but the problem seems to be the `<section>`. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has more than one problem.

The one you're currently stuck on is that `e` is not defined in this template bit:

```
<button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(e, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
```

The default name of the event when you want to pass it to the function is `event`, not `e` (and you can't change it, it's a convention - you can only change its name in the function). In other words, even if in the function it's named `e`, you still have to reference it as `event` in the template.

Here are the rest of the problems, in the order I encountered them as I worked my way into making it work:

- the `.tabs_button:active` selector is wrong. You probably want to use `.tabs_button.active` (since you're applying the class `active` to it).
- you have `tabs_content` class on the tabs wrapper, so the entire wrapper is hidden, when you probably only want to set `display:none` onto its children.
- you're missing the `id`s on second and third tab
- you need `width: 100%` on `.tabs_content`

See it here:

```js
function openPage(e, pageName) {
  let i, content, tabLinks;
  content = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs_content");
  for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    content[i].style.display = "none";
  }

  tabLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tabs_button");
  for (i = 0; i < tabLinks.length; i++) {
    tabLinks[i].className = tabLinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  
  document.getElementById(pageName).style.display = "block";
  e.currentTarget.className += " active";
}

document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav main ' 'nav main'
}

.tabs_sidebar {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #cccccc;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  min-height: 400px;
}

.tabs_content {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #f6e3e3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs_button {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tabs_button.active {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.tabs_button:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="tabs_sidebar">
    <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(event, 'Home')" id="defaultOpen">Home</button>
    <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(event, 'News')">News</button>
    <button class="tabs_button" onclick="openPage(event, 'Contact')">Contact</button>
  </nav>

  <section class="tabs_content--active">
    <div id="Home" class="tabs_content">
      <h2>Tab #1</h2>
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>

    <div id="News" class="tabs_content">
      <h2>Tab #2</h2>
      <p>News</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Contact" class="tabs_content">
      <h2>Tab #3</h2>
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Apart from that, in my estimation, you're doing too much by JavaScript. Instead of applying inline styles, you should only apply and remove classes which, in turn, apply styles. You end up writing less code and it's easier to manage & debug.
Another thing I would personally change is replace `className` usage with [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), which has a more powerful and more expressive syntax.

This doesn't mean it's not doable the way you set out to do it.

The main problem when mixing stylesheet CSS with inline styles is that inline styles can only be overwritten with `!important`, which leads to a whole new level of problems. By only applying classes you keep the specificity battle inside your stylesheet, which is where it should take place.

---

Here's how I'd write it:

```js
function openPage(e) {
  const target = e.target.dataset['target'];
  if (target) {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs_sidebar > button')].forEach(el => {
      el.classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
      document.getElementById(el.dataset['target'])
        .classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    })
  }
}

document.querySelector('.tabs_sidebar').addEventListener('click', openPage);
```

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 150px 1fr;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  padding: 15px;
  grid-template-areas: 'nav main'
}

.tabs_sidebar {
  grid-area: nav;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #cccccc;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.tabs_content--active > div {
  width: 100%;
  grid-area: main;
  background: #f6e3e3;
  padding-left: 15px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  display: none;
}

.tabs_content--active > div.active {
  display: block;
}

.tabs_sidebar > button {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #eeeeee;
  border: none;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.tabs_sidebar > button.active {
  background: #dddddd;
}

.tabs_sidebar > button:not(:last-of-type) {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <nav class="tabs_sidebar">
    <button data-target="Home" class="active">Home</button>
    <button data-target="News">News</button>
    <button data-target="Contact">Contact</button>
  </nav>

  <section class="tabs_content--active">
    <div id="Home" class="active">
      <h2>Tab #1</h2>
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>

    <div id="News">
      <h2>Tab #2</h2>
      <p>News</p>
    </div>

    <div id="Contact">
      <h2>Tab #3</h2>
      <p>Contact</p>
    </div>
  </section>

</div>
```

Note I've also made changes to markup (HTML) and CSS, not just JavaScript.

---

As requested in comments, here's an explanation on what the JavaScript code does:

Instead of placing a click handler on each individual button, I've placed one on their parent. It has the advantage of working on future buttons as well, should your page be dynamic. If you bind on each button, once the buttons change you have to figure out which ones are new and only bind the handler on those (you don't want to bind the handler twice on the same element).

When a click is performed inside that button container, you first have to determine which button was clicked (or if the click was outside of any existing buttons). See how data attributes work [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#javascript_access). If the click was performed on a button (`if (target)`), instead of having two loops (one through the buttons and one through the tabs), I only used one loop (through the buttons).

Instead of doing a classic `for` loop I chose to cast the NodeList returned by `querySelectorAll` to an array which I can then iterate using `.forEach()`.

***Note***: To be totally fair, I suspect the `for` loop (what you used) is more performant but the difference is quite small and I tend to go for the shorter syntax:

```
[...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs_sidebar > button')].forEach(el => {
  // do stuff with each looped element. In this case, a button
})
```

Now that we have the element, let's do something with it: **Add** or **remove** the class `active` based on whether or not the current button's target matches the one that was clicked (which we already have saved in `target` const).

I personally prefer `classList` to `className`. It works on the classes array, rather than on the resulting classes string. Has `add`, `remove` and `replace` methods and you don't end up having to worry about adding spaces manually (or trimming them). I'm using

```js
 el.classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
```

instead of

```js
if (el.dataset['target'] === target) {
  el.classList.add('active');
} else {
  el.classList.remove('active');
}
```

I used the array notation to call `add` and `remove` methods on `classList`. (i.e: in Javascript you can write `foo.bar(arg)` as `foo['bar'](arg)` - all methods are still object properties). The advantage is that inside the array notation you can switch the method being called, based on a ternary condition, which is exactly what I'm doing above.

Using the same technique, I'm also adding/removing the `active` class from the corresponding tab, which I'm selecting by `id`.

```js
document.getElementById(el.dataset['target'])
    .classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
```

The only thing that could slightly be improved about my code is saving the result of the ternary condition instead of doing it twice. Like this:

```js
 if (target) {
    [...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs_sidebar > button')].forEach(el => {
      const isActive = el.dataset['target'] === target;
      el.classList[isActive ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
      document.getElementById(el.dataset['target'])
        .classList[isActive ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
    })
  }
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lot @tao. One more question related to your optimized code: can you please explain a bit what the condensed JS function does  `if (target) {
            [...document.querySelectorAll('.tabs_sidebar > button')].forEach(el => {
              el.classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
              document.getElementById(el.dataset['target'])
                .classList[el.dataset['target'] === target ? 'add' : 'remove']('active');
            })`

Comment: @aerioeus, I've explained in detail what I'm doing. Let me know if anything is unclear. Also remember you can use `console.log()` pretty much anywhere in code to look at what variables contain at that stage. Another very powerful way of looking into what's happening when your code runs is `debugger;`. It stops the execution and automatically opens console at that point in code and you can hover the lines above and look into what each variable contains. Quite useful.

Comment: Merci @tao, that is very kind of you